# equivalent PHP sha1 in C#

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I am trying to find out how can i have the same result in php and C#.
I have this code in c#:

```
string date_server = "201311060930|aabbcc@test.com|test";
SHA1 sha_1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(date_server);
array = sha_1.ComputeHash(array);
```

And the result is: 2201676219018622422190124192121212501517223823286232147

So i want obtain the same result in PHP:

Code:

```
$finalString = "201311060930|aabbcc@test.com|test";
$a = utf8_encode($finalString);
$b = unpack('C*', $a); 
$string = implode($b);
$sHash = sha1($string);
```

But i can't obtain the same result: 3f24039aeb68e306f93161a9e9df2c44e7e1ce15

Thanks

Comment: You say you don't obtain the same result but you don't show what result you actually get. As for the problem I expect one is a decimal number and the other is a hexidecimal string

Comment: The result is: 3f24039aeb68e306f93161a9e9df2c44e7e1ce15

What can i do for obtain the same result?

Thanks

Comment: Convert one to conform to the other's format.  One's almost certainly a decimal and the other hex.

Comment: how to get 2201676219018622422190124192121212501517223823286232147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just run your c# code, the result should be

```
array = {68,176,83,152,44,38,107,201,112,139,17,80,242,94,158,181,136,198,98,193}
```

I dont know where the `2201676219018622422190124192121212501517223823286232147` comes from

[sha1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) will return the raw result if 2nd param is true, which you can convert into `array` (`byte[]` in C#) via `unpack`

```
$finalString = "201311060930|aabbcc@test.com|test";
$sHash = sha1($finalString, true);
echo join(',',unpack('C*', $sHash));
```

and the output is same to C#

```
68,176,83,152,44,38,107,201,112,139,17,80,242,94,158,181,136,198,98,193
```